# java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: HTTP/1.1 422��Unprocessable Entity

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm making a POST request using Retrofit + Okhttp, and I'm running into the following error:

```
02-05 04:45:13.981  15972-16249/com.myapp.android D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP POST http://10.0.0.4:3000/api/v1/users/1/posts
02-05 04:45:13.981  15972-16249/com.myapp.android D/Retrofit﹕ Accept: application/json
02-05 04:45:13.981  15972-16249/com.myapp.android D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
02-05 04:45:13.981  15972-16249/com.myapp.android D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Length: 150
02-05 04:45:13.981  15972-16249/com.myapp.android D/Retrofit﹕ {"description":"test","image_url":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/xxx-4800-b0e0-fc206f95f158.jpeg","title":"test","price":0.0,"user_id":0}
02-05 04:45:13.981  15972-16249/com.myapp.android D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (150-byte body)
02-05 04:45:14.001  15972-15972/com.myapp.android W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-05 04:45:14.017  15972-16249/com.myapp.android D/Retrofit﹕ ---- ERROR http://10.0.0.4:3000/api/v1/users/1/posts
02-05 04:45:14.017  15972-16249/com.myapp.android D/Retrofit﹕ java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: HTTP/1.1 422��Unprocessable Entity
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StatusLine.parse(StatusLine.java:73)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:187)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:791)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:90)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:784)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:645)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:263)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:219)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:192)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
            at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$1.invoke(RestAdapter.java:265)
            at retrofit.RxSupport$2.run(RxSupport.java:55)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-05 04:45:14.017  15972-16249/com.myapp.android D/Retrofit﹕ ---- END ERROR
```

Using the following libs:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
```

I'm expecting something like the following to come back (intentionally testing a 422 error):

```
{
    "title": [
        "is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"
    ]
}
```

I get the expected result when sending via Postman (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)

**Edit:**
I'm making the following call in Rails to return this 422 result:

```
render json: @post.errors.to_json, status: :unprocessable_entity
```

**Another Edit:**

Here's a screenshot of the request being made via Wireshark. Nothing looks out of the ordinary, but I've also never used the tool before.

[image: Overall]

Here's the appropriate hex.

[image: Hex]

Comment: i have same error. did you find a solution?

Comment: @savepopulation unfortunately no. Fortunately it just started working. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Yeah... I know that's a terrible answer, but it's the truth :)

Comment: when i checked server logs there's an unhandled  exception which causes returning not a valid response from server. so retrofit gets an status line exception.

Answer (score 7):

Your server appears to violate the HTTP spec. The status line is defined as follows:

> The first line of a response message is the status-line, consisting
>   of the protocol version, a space (SP), the status code, another
>   space, a possibly empty textual phrase describing the status code,
>   and ending with CRLF.
>
> ```
> status-line = HTTP-version SP status-code SP reason-phrase CRLF
> ```

From the exception it appears that a non-space character (or two) is between the status code and reason phrase.

OkHttp is looking for ASCII spaces (character #32) between these elements. You can use something like WireShark or maybe Charles to intercept the network traffic and figure out what characters are being used by your HTTP server.

Comment: That's strange. I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary with Rails (not much more than a "Hello World" sort of app. I'll take a look using what you suggested and see if it sheds any light.

Comment: Yeah I'd be curious to know what's happening here. I don't think I've seen something like this before. Getting the hex values of those characters would help identify. I can also go spelunking in Rails eventually, but not right now.

Comment: I definitely saw this return correctly before. I'm having a hard time tracking down what I changed since or what variables would have been introduced. I added the line of code that *should* be generating this response in my original question.

Comment: I have wireshark up and running. I updated my question with more info.

Comment: Huh. That hex looks completely reasonable. Did that response end up producing the same error in the client?

Comment: It did, yeah. Same result/error. Is there something I might be doing wrong client side? I think I'm doing a pretty typical Observable call.