# Unexpected status line exception using HttpUrlConnection in android?

Tags: java, android, https, okhttp

I have developed an Android app which sends/gets some data to/from server. The app works fine, however, on Android KitKat 4.4.2 the app throws an exception:

> "java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: ��".

Please tell me how to get rid of it and why this is happening

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
    con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url[0]).openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having same problem.
Looks that was due to recycling  connection.

> con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");

did the trick
(Or use addHeader, if still using Apache Http)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe OkHttp solves your problem:

http://square.github.io/okhttp/

> You can try out OkHttp without rewriting your network code. The
>   okhttp-urlconnection module implements the familiar
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection API and the okhttp-apache module implements
>   the Apache HttpClient API.

Note: OkHttp is standard in Android 5. So why not use it in lower versions :)

Comment: Why this problem occur ?

Comment: Maybe your Server response is not correct. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336457/java-net-protocolexception-unexpected-status-line-http-1-1-422%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BDunprocessable

Comment: Response of server is some sort of strange string which my app is not able to read when i catch the exception app gets crashed..