# Retrofit 2 error ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: array(5)

Tags: android, interceptor, retrofit2

i added retrofit 2 to my android app.
I intercept my requests to add a jwt header.
i don't understand what's not working with my interceptors :

```
class ApiInterceptor implements Interceptor {

@Override
public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

    Request request = chain.request();
    Response response = null;

    SharedPreferences preferences = MyApplication.getAppContext()
            .getSharedPreferences("LWUserPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    // Do anything with request here
    // set api token
    // if not route api/login
    if (!"/api/login".equalsIgnoreCase(request.url().encodedPath())) {
        String apiToken = preferences.getString("apiToken", null);
        // set authorization header
        request = request.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiToken)
                .build();

        response = chain.proceed(request);
        [...]
```

I get this error message :

```
02-22 22:14:01.006 8588-8588/debug W/System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: array(5) {
02-22 22:14:01.007 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.StatusLine.parse(StatusLine.java:54)
02-22 22:14:01.007 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponse(Http1xStream.java:185)
02-22 22:14:01.007 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.readResponseHeaders(Http1xStream.java:126)
02-22 22:14:01.007 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:707)
02-22 22:14:01.007 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:81)
02-22 22:14:01.007 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:692)
02-22 22:14:01.007 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:547)
02-22 22:14:01.007 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:242)
02-22 22:14:01.007 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:199)
02-22 22:14:01.007 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at api.ApiInterceptor.intercept(ApiClient.java:100)
02-22 22:14:01.007 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:188)
02-22 22:14:01.007 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
02-22 22:14:01.007 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:188)
02-22 22:14:01.008 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:161)
02-22 22:14:01.008 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
02-22 22:14:01.008 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
02-22 22:14:01.008 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
02-22 22:14:01.008 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
02-22 22:14:01.008 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
02-22 22:14:01.008 8588-8588/debug W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Any ideas ?
(running server with laravel 5.2)

Comment: Hi @Mushu8, could you resolve it ?

Comment: @cgr I could not solve the problem, only patched it by adding a header to each request : ```request.newBuilder().header("Connection", "close")…```
the problem is about keep-alive connection with the server i guess…

Comment: @cgr if you have more informations i would be happy to read it

Comment: I am yet to analyse the issue further.I will chare when I get any useful info. Thanks!

Comment: "bad closed" - you mean ?

Comment: @cgr http://stackoverflow.com/a/28351733/2728302
in my case ```array(5) {``` in the error message is the beginning of my response body

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106366/discussion-between-mushu8-and-cgr).